# JQuery + PHP - PHP returning nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using JQuery to call a php script.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#div1").html("<img border='0' src='/images/ajax_loader_blue_32.gif'>");
    $.ajax({url:"process_casper.php",success:function(result){
      $("#div1").html(result);
    }});
  });
});
```

This code works, only if I echo "test"; at the top of my php scrip.  And of course the output is "test".  However, if I try and let the php scrip run (takes about 20 seconds) then nothing is returned.

PHP script:

```
    require_once("libs/simple_html_dom.php");

    $filename = "data/okbnetplaza_" . date('Y-m-d_H:i:s') . ".txt";
    exec("casperjs /root/okbnetplaza.js  --uid=removed --pin=removed > $filename");

    // Create a DOM object
    $html = new simple_html_dom();

    // Load HTML from a URL 
    $html->load_file($filename);
    foreach($html->find('td[class=txtRight]') as $td) 
    {
           foreach($td->find('.txtBold') as $val) 
           {
                echo $val->plaintext;
           }
    }
```

When I run the scrip in command line, it only returns the one line of text that I need.

What am I doing wrong that causes nothing to be returned?

Comment: may be php page is out of memory

Comment: Maybe you don't have the access to perform an `exec`

Comment: did you ever test that php without jquery? what happened? is the result shown?

Comment: the data set is very small, the process just takes time to retrieve it.

Comment: @OkiErieRinaldi Yes, I run the scrip in command line and it works fine the result is a single line of text

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran when I run the script in command line it works, do you think Apache does not have permissions to run exec?

Comment: @Rioku, I am afraid yes.

Comment: Is the php page on another domain?

Comment: Can you check headers and returning result in your browser console? I'm sure it will give a clue

Comment: @Kuzgun I have checked the headers, response and HTML.  Headers look fine. response and html are blank  :(

Comment: @Kuzgun PHP scrip is right next to webpage

Comment: If you echo file name, do you get it with ajax?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran I am trying to figure out how to change user for apache. Do you know if there is a way to test for permissions error?

Comment: 'td[class=txtRight]': Are you sure that this is a valid DOM selection? Have you tried replacing this with 'td.txtRight'?

Comment: @MichaelZalla ya, when I run the script in command line it works fine.

Comment: Try to set permission executable for Everyone user from that file's properties>security

Comment: Hey Everyone, it turned out to be several permission issues. One was the casper script being in root. The second was apache not being able to write to the "data" directory.  Anyone want to post and answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that issues was related to permissions.  The exec command was creating a file but it did not have permissions to create the file.  Once I changed the permissions on where the files was to be created then the script worked.

Thanks for the help!